# Array of int to string conversion in C

Tags: arrays, c, parsing

I'm trying to convert an array of integers into a string in C.
FOr instance I have the following code:

```
 int number[] = {1,3,2,0};
 char c[5];
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++ ){
        c[i] = number[i];
    }
printf("%s", c);
```

It however outputs smiley faces or hearts and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

When you `printf` characters, it takes the [ASCII symbol](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) for that number.

Your numbers 1, 3, 2, 0 are `SOH`, `ETX`, `STX`, which are non-printable characters.

Try the numbers 65, 66 for example, they are letters.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is not giving you any output as it will not compile.

It is hard to say what you want to archive but here you have an example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int number[] = {1,3,2,0};
    char c[sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]) + 1] = {0,};
    char d[sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0])][10];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++ ){
        c[i] = number[i] % 10 + '0';
        snprintf(d[i], 10, "%d", number[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", c);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++ ){
        printf("%s\n",d[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you extract `sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]` into a `numberSize` and reuse it, or does it have to be a compile time constant?

Comment: @Alexander does it matter in this example?

Comment: Magic number 10 in `char d[sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0])][10];` deserves a comment.  I'd expect 12 to handle all 32-bit `int`.